# PHP how to hide text from users who are not logged in?

Tags: php, logging, cookies

Please tell me a way on how to make that if the user has not logged-in the site, he cannot see specific text, instead he will see something like "This content is only for registered users. To register click here." Or something around that way...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `SESSION['user_id']` value for the logged user

and u apply the logic on that specific div

```
if(!isset(SESSION['user_id']) || empty(SESSION['user_id']))
{
   echo "Please <a href='register.php'>login/register</a> to view this content";
}
else
{
 <div>
              // your content and whatever
 </div>
}
```

Comment: you can also do the same with `COOKIES`, instead of `SESSION`

Answer (score 1):

Pass your text from some conditions and check before echoing it. For an example

Check if the user is logged in though session variable directly or you can create method/function for this

```
if (is_user_logged_in() === TRUE)
{
  echo $content;
}
else
{
    echo "This content is only for registered users. To register click here."
}
```

This is just a simple example.

Comment: singh, where he said that he is using **wordpress** , bcoz `is_user_logged_in()` is wordpress function, otherwise u need to define that function in core php

Comment: @diEcho: And I am also not talking about wordpress here I wrote `you can create method/function for this` and at the end `This is just a simple example.`